# Looping through all elements of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe

I am trying to loop through a dataframe that is 4x3 with the following code:

```
R = []
Ratio = pd.DataFrame(R)
for column in Three_Distances:
     column_location = Three_Distances.columns.get_loc(column)
     for rows, row in Three_Distances.iterrows():

         if column == 'post_one':
             Ratio[column_location,rows] = 
                   1/Three_Distances[column].divide(D1_theoretical)
         if column == 'post_two':
             Ratio[column_location,rows] = 
                   1/Three_Distances[column].divide(D2_theoretical)
         if column == 'post_three':
             Ratio[column_location,rows] = 
                  1/Three_Distances[column].divide(D3_theoretical)
```

My output for variable Ratio is 4x12 instead of 4x3. I am wondering if I am not properly understanding the tools or loops that I am using?

Thanks

Comment: please read this before posting; [ask], [mcve]

Comment: `print(Ratio)` and show us your dataframe, Then we can help you easily

Comment: (0, 0)    (0, 1)    (0, 2)    (0, 3)    (1, 0)    (1, 1)    (1, 2)  \
0  2.997553  2.997553  2.997553  2.997553  2.956921  2.956921  2.956921   
1  2.920048  2.920048  2.920048  2.920048  2.825219  2.825219  2.825219   
2  2.741152  2.741152  2.741152  2.741152  2.806497  2.806497  2.806497   
3  2.841114  2.841114  2.841114  2.841114  2.862783  2.862783  2.862783 .....and so on until column (2,3)